# What does "cacheParamsComputed" mean in Swift 4?

Tags: xcode, macos, warnings, xcode9, swift4

I just upgraded one of my macOS app written in Swift 3 to Swift 4, and got the following warnings:

- 'cacheParamsComptued' is depreacated
- 'keepCacheWindow' is deprecated

However, even if I tapped on the triangle icon nothing changed in Xcode.

What does this warning mean and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Seems like a [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2321) in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this.  Simply cleaning the project (Shift-Command-K) and rebuilding (Command-B) made it go away.